# CentOS 7 vsftpd incorrect folder permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, centos-7, vsftpd

I'm faced with two issues right now. I cannot write to the `/var/www/*` folders and I am able to traverse backward into the /var and / root directory!

I'm using vsftpd and in the config I'm using the chroot_list and have added a local account. The account is apart of a group www-acc. I guess I should also mention the local_umask=022.

I tried to assign the group www-acc permissions to the directory `/var/www/`. I also changed the home directory for the user but it still seems they're able to browse the entire drive.

I'd like the user who has the group www-acc to only be allowed in /var/www/*. What can I do to successfully accomplish this?

`ls -la` for `/var/www` shows:

```
total 4
drwxr-sr-x.  4 root www-acc   49 Sep 21 14:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root    4096 Sep 19 21:26 ..
drwxr-sr-x.  2 root www-acc    6 Jun 27 09:49 cgi-bin
drwxrwsr-x.  3 root www-acc   25 Sep 20 21:32 example.com
```

Comment: I fixed the inability to write to all folders within /var/www with:

Comment: sudo chown -R user:group /var/www
    sudo setfacl -R -d -m u:user:rwx,g:group:rwx,o::r /var/www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed both issues. First I disabled a couple of options in the vsftpd.conf and then changed permissions on the directory again.

vsftpd.conf:

```
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
```

Permissions were changed with:

```
sudo chown -R user:group /var/www 
sudo setfacl -R -d -m u:user:rwx,g:group:rwx,o::r /var/www
```